# How to store every file change indefinitely?

Tags: dropbox, google-drive, editing, version-control

How can I automatically save the entire change history of the files on my computer indefinitely?

Dropbox stores file version history only intermittently and only for the past 30 days.

The solution I want would save *every* file change (down to the T) along with the date & time of the change, such that if I were to replay all the changes, I'd get an accurate time lapse of my editing the file. And, it would persist all file version histories indefinitely.

Comment: You could probably whip something up with PowerShell such as [Powershell FileSystemWatcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) and further expand to save the file per each date modified change with a file name appended `_YYYYMMDDhhmmssttt` and just have it save to a copy directory maybe with `/YYYYMMDD` folder name and you could see every revision of every file that way. If someone wants to take a stab at a PowerShell type solution of this nature, I'd love to test with such a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Although not exactly what you are looking for, Windows 8 & 10 have a tool that might meet your needs.  The `File History` tool will allow you to save file versions in as little as 10 minute increments and you can keep those versions forever.

Here is a good [article](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2974385/windows/how-to-use-windows-10s-file-history-backup-feature.html) on its usage.

Just a note of warning.  Depending on the size and amount of files you are backing up, as well as the frequency of changes, you might need a large amount of storage.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Windows you can enable [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832(v=vs.85).aspx), but it will create a backup on a fixed time schedule

http://thesolving.com/storage/configuring-volume-shadow-copies-vss-on-windows-server-2012-r2/